# Drop a Sortable Element

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I've had a look around and tried some answers here on SOF, it seems problems may be running deeper.

- Take a look at http://miuzer.com/newx/.
- Login top-right (test:password)
- Now search for "cage" and you should see a track appear.
- The idea is you drag that sortable track element over the
  playlist on the left and it triggers the add track function.

Please read here for the apparent solution that is not working in my code: [jQuery Sortable and Droppable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090121/jquery-sortable-and-droppable)

http://miuzer.com/newx/js/playlist.js - line 127 is the sortable event.
http://miuzer.com/newx/js/sidebar.js - handles the drop.

What happens at the moment is that the drop event isn't called at all.

If anyone can help, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're attempting to call a variable, 'dropped', which is out of scope from playlist.js. I suppose one (dirty) solution would be to set dropped as a global variable like window.dropped. That way you could access it from playlist.js  - Hope this helps a little

hacknightly

Comment: dropped is declared at the top of sidebar.js just like draggable_sibling, I thought it was already global. draggable_sibling get it's values set successfully inside that playlist.js function so I don't think scope is the issue. Tis a mystery!