# Two jquery-ui sortables connected, how to change droppable target?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two sortables connected by means of jQuery sortable plugin. Is it possible to change target for draggables for one of them? I want to drag not from #sortable1 to #sortable2, but to $('#sortable').parent(), because #sortable2 is too small. Making it larger spoils html layout.

```
$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
}).disableSelection();

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Here is a demo:  https://jsfiddle.net/uq3vu5ne/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve here.
You want your parent div to get the height of your second sortable or your sortables to have a fixed height?

If it's the first you can remove the static height. If it's the latter you can add fixed height and scroll to your sortables.

**UPDATE:** I think you need sortable/droppable take a look at this post please.

[jQuery Sortable and Droppable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4362061/2321666)

Comment: i want to be able to drag not to sortable2, but to its parent area. it should be highlighted and recieve dragged object as if it was sortable2